# CUDA compile error on Linux, but Windows Visual Studio succeed

Tags: c++, cuda

This program can build successfully on Windows - Visual Studio 12, but I got some problem when I compile it on Linux.

Compile command : `nvcc main.cu`

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    ... (Skip some code)

    // Read file.
    MemoryBuffer<char> text(size + 1); // size type is size_t
    auto text_smem = text.CreateSync(size);
    fread(text_smem.get_cpu_wo(), 1, size, fp);

    ... (Skip some code)

}
```

Compiler error message:

1. `auto text_smem = text.CreateSync(size);`

   occured about **`error: explicit type is missing ("int" assumed)`** and **`error: no suitable conversion function from "SyncedMemory<char>" to "int" exists`**
2. `fread(text_smem.get_cpu_wo(), 1, size, fp);`

   occured about **`error: expression must have class type`**

How to solve the compiler error in Linux OS?

---

MemoryBuffer is a class, detail code can see from [here](https://gist.github.com/grass0916/0ac6871137b845348dc6).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on version of CUDA Toolkit, that you have installed, but I guess you could try with `--std=c++11` option to the `nvcc`, in order to explicitely enable modern C++ features.

Reffering to https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/power-cpp11-cuda-7/

> To enable C++11 support, pass the flag `--std=c++11` to `nvcc` (this
>   option is not required for Microsoft Visual Studio).